# Enabling OpenGL extensions

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm trying to perform some integer operations (division and modulo) in my GLSL shader, but they don't seem to work and I read that I need to enable `EXT_GPU_shader4` in order to get integer operations.  What I can't find, however, is how to do that.  Is the line:

```
#version 330 core
#extension GL_EXT_GPU_SHADER4 : require
```

enough?  Or do I need to enable it using the C API somehow too?  Currently I get an error during compilation that the extension is not supported.  I'm on a GeForce 670; a pretty recent card.

Comment: This answer will solve most of your problems: stackoverflow.com/questions/11584515/passthrough-geometry-shader

Comment: That's valid, but redundant. Version 330 already includes integer support. Using "require" instead of "enable" will result in an error if the extension is not available. Note that the extension does not necessarily _have to_ be supported if the core already supports it (it need not be supported at all of course, but even if the card supports integer operations, and even if the core version including the feature is supported, the implementation isn't required to expose that extension, too).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the functionality of EXT_gpu_shader4 is already available with: `#version 150 core`.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right.  Thanks!  It turns out my results were all crazy because LWJGL (or OpenGL?) was converting my buffers from int -> float, and I had an 'in int var' bound to the buffer.  So I was trying to do integer operations on the binary representation of floats, which were converted from my original input data...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to enable GPU_shader4, then yes, that line will do it.

*However*, you shouldn't be enabling EXT_gpu_shader4 *at all.* OpenGL 3.0 already incorporates all of this extension into core functionality. There's no reason to enable an extension to access stuff you already have access to thanks to your `#version` declaration.